# Will recover from recovery disks created from recovery partition restore the recovery partition?

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, recovery-disk, recovery-partition

My laptop is Lenovo T400 with Windows 7.

After creation of recovery disks from a recovery partition, if the recovery partition is deleted, will recovery from the recovery disks restore the recovery partition?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: Yes to me. For one, I was wondering if a backup will restore itself. Second, I want to know if I can create recovery disks from the restored recovery partition again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the full set of recovery disks will do so. That's what they are meant to do, after all. You're out of luck if you loose those disks, naturally.

Comment: This.  The recovery disks put the factory image back on, which includes the F11 recovery partition.  (They do not let you make another set of disks, though- that's the only change.)

Comment: of course, you could make ISOs of rhe recovery disks ;p

Comment: @Shinrai: Is "F11 recovery partition" same as recovery partition? Why use F11 in front?

Comment: @Tim - Because of my responses to your other questions, I'm trying to be clear that the recovery environment and the Q partition are *not the same thing*.

Comment: cause in many systems F11 lets you go to the recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. If the recovery disk is just a boot loader, then it requires the recovery partition, as that is where the backup of the main partition is stored.  Unless the recovery disks are multiple DVDs (in this case the recovery partition would be stored on the DVDs), then you require the recovery partition on the HDD in order to restore.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think you understand my question. I have burned 2 DVDs from my recovery partition and then I deleted the recovery partition. I was asking if the recovery partition will be recovered from the disks.

Comment: Ahh, OK, so you have a full set of recovery disks. It is unlikely that they will restore the recovery partition, this is probably vendor, and possibly model, specific. You may get a better answer from IBM/Lenovo support. I suppose, theoretically, the recovery partition may be copied from the recovery disks, you would need to know what app was used to image the partition though. Look for the biggest file on the recovery DVDs, maybe the file extension will give you an idea of what app can be used to view/copy/restore the image.

Comment: @Tim - Judging from your previous questions, you haven't deleted the recovery partition.  You've deleted the data store for the recovery disks.

Comment: @Shinrai: I have deleted the partition and free up its space.

Comment: @Tim - The one you see in Windows is not the recovery partition.  To actually delete the startup recovery functionality you have to manually remove it from Rescue and Recovery (unless they've very recently changed this.)  Press F11 at boot and see for yourself.